# how an overloaded function is internally represented during compilation process in c++

Tags: c++, c, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++ how is function overloading typically implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227516/in-c-how-is-function-overloading-typically-implemented)

i was going through bruce eckel's book on `OOPS` which stated about working about the overloaded functions in case when they have difference in return values and the arguments passed.

---

```
int fun() :: could be represented as __int__fun
float fun():: could be represented as __float__fun
int fun(int a):: as _int _fun_int
```

but how does the overloading works in case of blocks in c

```
               {
                  void fun(){}
                  ...........
                  ..
                  fun()
               }
               /......sme code/
               {
                   void fun(){}
               }
```

can anyone explain how does this is represented internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, two functions with the same name in different blocks are named like so:

`functionName.number`

For example, you might have:

`fun.2051`

and

`fun.2053`

I figured this out by compiling a C program with the following command:

`gcc -S -o test.asm test.c`

I then opened up the assembly file and observed what gcc labeled the functions with.

Answer (score 4):

Defining functions inside blocks is not legal in C++.

If we imagine for one brief second such things are legal, your two functions are still not overloaded. They simply have scopes that do not overlap. Your example isn't different from this one:

```
  {
     int i;
     ...
  }
  {
     int i;
     ...
  }
```

There is no "overloaded variable" here, and no overloaded function in your example.

Comment: actually that was a typo .i was asking in case of c as c permits it. how are they implemented in c .what hapens when compiler sees such definations.how are they resolved?

Comment: C doesn't permit overloading though.  Crappy question in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A block can only happen inside a function. C++ does not support/allow nested functions (i.e., one function defined inside another function) so the question never arises.

If it was allowed (e.g. by a compiler like gcc as an extension) you still wouldn't get overloading. Overloading requires that two (or more) entities with the same basic name are visible within the same scope. In this case, each name would be in a separate scope, in which case overloading doesn't happen -- you just have normal scoped lookup, which finds the name from the most local scope that matches.

Edit: As an aside, I should also add that contrary to what you've shown, the return type of a function probably isn't normally included in the mangled/decorated name -- function overloading depends on the function "signature", which includes the parameter types, but *not* the return type.

Comment: Namespaces. Also, [you can use nested function by putting them into local classes](http://pastebin.com/uewsG2mx).

Comment: @SigTerm: Despite the superficial similar in syntax, the braces in a namespace don't define a "block", at least as the term is normally used (i.e., what C or C++ would call a "compound statement"). You can define local classes, but as noted in my answer, that still won't result in overloading.

Answer (score 0):

> how an overloaded function is internally represented during compilation process in c++

Google "C++ [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)". It'll be represented like a normal function with a name similar to this `writeCDATA@QXmlStreamWriter@@QAEXABVQString@@@Z`

> but how does the overloading works in case of blocks

Your code example doesn't contain valid C++ code and will not compile.