# How compiler differentiates between over-loaded functions

Tags: c++, overriding, overloading

I understand what function overloading is. But, I am curious how compiler differentiates these overloaded functions. Let's say, I have the following two overloaded functions definitions.

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int a, int b);
int sum(vector<int> a, vector<int> b);
```

So, How does compiler decided which function to call? I understand the logic, it differentiates based on the data types of the argument. But, how is it implemented?

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227516/in-c-how-is-function-overloading-typically-implemented?

Comment: _"But, how is it implemented?"_ By the compilers type parsing logic?

Comment: [Name mangling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) is one piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I put some examples in an answer, including using conversions

Comment: The compiler breaks all functions up by <name> and <inputs> when you call the function, the compiler looks up the name and then starts trying to match the input types. The rules for matching the inputs can be long and scary but mostly it just boils down to looking for an exact match first, then trying available implicit type conversions to get the match. tldr  Now think of each part of a function as a "token" like name, type1, type2. Name is literally a string, the types come from a list that is built as the program is compiled. The call is broken into similar tokens. Now it is easy to match.

Answer (score 1):

As you said all depends on the argument types, may be through a conversion :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int sum(int, int)
{
  cout << "ints" << endl;
}

int sum(vector<int>, vector<int>)
{
  cout << "vectors" << endl;
}

class C1 {
  public:
    operator int() { return 0; }
};

class C2 {
  public:
    operator int() { return 0; }
    operator vector<int>() { vector<int> v ; return v; }
};

int main()
{
  sum(1, 2); // ints
  sum(1.2, 3); // ints, use conversion from double to int

  vector<int> v;

  sum(v, v); // vectors
  // sum(v, 0); no matching function for call to 'sum(std::vector<int>&, int)'


  C1 c1;

  sum(c1, c1); // use conversion from C1 to int

  C2 c2;

  //sum(c2, c2);  call of overloaded 'sum(C2&, C2&)' is ambiguous

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
ints
ints
vectors
ints
```