# No naming conflict from two functions in global namespace (C++)?

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, global

I created two files, `Linkage.cpp` and `External.cpp`.

`Linkage.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

void Log(int x = 5)
{
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Log();
    return 0;
}
```

`External.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

void Log(const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message << "\n";
}
```

Why am I not getting a linker error? Both these functions are defined in the global namespace, so there should be naming conflicts as with variables.

Comment: Why would there be a conflict? They don't have the same signature.

Comment: Could you please explain more? What's a function signature?

Comment: In order for two functions to be considered the same they need to have the same name and parameters. Do you know what function overloading is? [In C++ how is function overloading typically implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227516/in-c-how-is-function-overloading-typically-implemented)

Comment: They could even be in the same file. No problem. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/GPTMKKEhE)

Comment: Note though that the _return type_ of the function often doesn't matter. For example, you can't have both `int foo();` and `double foo();`. That would cause ambiguity. More on that here: [Is the return type part of the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I not getting a linker error?

When you wrote

```
void Log(int x = 5)//this means that the function named Log can be called without passing 
                  //any argument because you have provided a default argument which will be 
                 //used in case you don't provide/pass any argument
{
   //..other code here
{
```

The above means that the function named `Log` can be called without passing any argument because you have provided a default argument which will be used in case you don't provide/pass any argument.

**Next** when you wrote

```
void Log(const char* message)//this means that this versoin of the function named Log will be called only if you pass an argument of type `char*` . 
{
    std::cout << message << "\n";
}
```

The above means that this verion of the function named `Log` will be called **only if** you pass an argument of type `char*` .

Now when your wrote:

```
 Log();
```

The first version which has a default argument will be used because you haven't provided any argument and so the first version can be used(since it is **viable**) and because the second version which must take an argument is **not viable**.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I experimented around after @Retire Ninja pointed this out to me.

First, comment out all the code from `External.cpp`. Now, declare another `Log` function inside `Linkage.cpp` so that there are two functions inside this file that have the same name(Log) but different parameters. You will realise that using depending upon what arguments you supply, these `Log` functions will behave like different functions.

So, unlike variables, where same name means same variable in a namespace, functions need to have matching ***signatures*** too.